# Error in storing data through API

Tags: php, html, api

I want to call the data from API to store in my variable.
My Code:

```
<?php $url = "https://api.steampowered.com/ICSGOServers_730/GetGameMapsPlaytime/v1/?format=json&key=E5F331493A95AA54FD1230551754AB19&mapgroup=operation&gamemode=casual&interval=month";

$mapinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$b = $mapinfo['result'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Operation Maps Stats</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo "$b"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:
Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\operation\index.php on line 14
Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `print_r($b);` instead of `echo "$b"` on line 14 because result is array.

Answer (score 0):

Line 14:    `<?php echo "$b"; ?>`
You have to change to `<?php echo $b; ?>`
Because you are treating `$b` like a string